# Yesod Hamlet breaks HTML by replacing single quotes with double quotes

Tags: yesod, hamlet

I have some HTML code that I'm using in Hamlet:

```
 <div .modal-card .card data-options='{"valueNames": ["name"]}' data-toggle="lists">
```

Notice that the single quotes for `data-options` allows the use of double quotes inside the string.

The problem is that when Hamlet renders the page, Hamlet puts `"` around the `'` and so the HTML is broken:

```
<div class="modal-card card" data-options="'{" valuenames":"="" ["name"]}'="" data-toggle="lists">
```

Some external JS library plugin code runs, it tries to parse the JSON inside `data-options` and fails.

**How can I tell Hamlet to include a literal string?**

I've tried various combinations of:

```
let theString = "{\"valueNames\": [\"name\"]}"
let theString2 = "data-options='{\"valueNames\": [\"name\"]}'"
etc
```

And in the hamlet file:

```
 <div .modal-card .card data-options='#{ preEscapedText theString }' data-toggle="lists">
or
 <div .modal-card .card #{ preEscapedText theString2 } data-toggle="lists">
```

But all attempts produce invalid HTML or invalid JSON inside the string.

**How can I instruct Hamlet to simply include a literal string in the output HTML?**

Update:

Tried more things, no result.

The `string2` example doesn't work because Hamlet seems to think that I'm trying to set `id="{"` as per https://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates#shakespearean-templates_attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not render the JSON escaped (`"` become `&quot;`) and “handle” the quotes later when parsing?

Interpolate in Hamlet:

```
<div #the-modal .modal-card .card data-options='#{theString}' data-toggle="lists">
```

Parse the data attribute as JSON:

```
let json = document.getElementById("the-modal").getAttribute("data-options");
let opts = JSON.parse(json); // At least in Chrome, it works!
```

As for `theString2` alternative, you can also [interpolate attributes in Hamlet](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates#shakespearean-templates_attributes) using a tuple or list of tuples and the star symbol:

```
let dataOptions = ("data-options", "{\"valueNames\": [\"name\"]}") :: (Text, Text)
...
<div #the-modal .modal-card .card *{dataOptions} data-toggle="lists">
```

Comment: I will try these Alexandre! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The `*{dataOptions}` method worked! Thankyou!! כֹּל הַכָּבוֹד